# ActionScript 3 Mouse Out

Tags: actionscript, mouse, invisible, out, animated

I'm creating an animated (in and out) drop down menu.
I've managed to get the menu to open when the user mouses over, with the buttons all selectable.
However I can't seem to find an efficient method of making the drop down menu close whenever the mouse is not over the menu.

Actions:

```
Nav_Main_Sports.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, Nav_Main_Sports_Open);
Nav_Main_Sports_Out.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);

function Nav_Main_Sports_Open(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function Nav_Main_Sports_Close(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(14);
}
```

Stops are included, but on a separate layer.

All help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Share the code you have otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: I've added an example of my code, however it is somewhat uncompleted because of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions:

```
Nav_Main_Sports.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, Nav_Main_Sports_Open);
Nav_Main_Sports.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);

function Nav_Main_Sports_Open(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Nav_Main_Sports.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function Nav_Main_Sports_Close(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Nav_Main_Sports.gotoAndPlay(14);
}
```

Worked out the best method for this, use ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT and refer to the drop down menu in the function. This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Nav_Main_Sports.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);`

EDIT:
If you want to get the event on the whole swf, do `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);`

Comment: I don't want the event to be applied to the entire swf, but with the code you have given me it does not seem to be working correctly.

Comment: Basically with this I am unable to move down onto the drop down menu because the drop down closes.

Comment: Then add the event to the drop down menu MovieClip, instead of `Nav_Main_Sports`.

Comment: Just done this, it works to a certain extent, but now when I mouse over any of the buttons on the drop down menu it thinks I've mouse out of the drop down movie clip.

Comment: Are the buttons child of the drop down menu? I have no idea how your assets are organized so it's very hard to tell you a perfect solution.

Comment: They're on a layer above, how can I make them a child?

Comment: Do this then: either `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);` or `parent..addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);`, depending on how things are organized.

Comment: How should I organise my drop down menu? I have 3 layers, 1 with the ActionScript, 1 with the buttons and 1 with the background.

Comment: Your organization sounds correct to me. You need to add the event to the entire drop down menu, not just the background or something else. Where is the code event code located at?

Comment: On the top layer named actions.

Comment: If it's inside the drop down menu, then use `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, Nav_Main_Sports_Close);`.  Consider upvoting and accepting my answer.